# Android development with notepad-like editor and command line

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I have a problem with Eclipse. It is very slow for me. My PC is an old PC and I'm not comfort with the performance. Is there any lightweight alternative to Eclipse (Available for Windows and Linux)? I want SPEED!

My ideal is to write my code in an editor like Notepad and supplement with the command line! How can I compile my code in this environment? How do I update my R.java file or build my project's configuration?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432812/how-to-set-up-android-sdk-for-command-line-development-on-linux
and:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538649/text-command-line-based-java-ide?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) provides very nice instructions about using the command line tool. The building is performed with the aid of Ant tool. You could also use a more advanced editor than notepad (Notepad++ for example).

However, if you have a slow machine, you would suffer during development anyway. You should also forget about using the emulator for debugging. The emulator would take ages to load.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

see the link [managing project through command line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

It provides a brief description about how to develop android app without any IDE

Comment: this link is dead. posting links is discouraged exactly because of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed, you should buy a faster computer.

It seems that you are a beginner -> I would suggest purchasing almost any java book, or visiting websites with tutorials, if you are at the stage where you don't know how to compile your code.

Comment: You're not addressing any of the questions by OP. The question was how to develop android using the command line and a lightweight editor. Instead, you're making assumptions about OPs budget as well as their level of expertise and provide answers to problems you think are relevant. This is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

well, nothing holds you back to use notepad and manually compiling with javac:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Like kgiannakakis pointed out; you'll also need the Android SDK:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: javac compiler isn't enough. You also need the android sdk in order to build the R class for example.